# Basic Registration Form with PHP

Tags: php, session, registration

Can you please help me. I'm a beginner in PHP and still learning the basics of the language. I'm currently learning how to create sessions. Apparently there's a bug when I try out one of the examples in the book. The HTML form looks like this:

```
<form action="session_registration_form_script.php" method="post">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```

and the PHP script is something like:

```
<?php

    // Initialize session data
    session_start();

    /*
     * If the user is already registered, display a 
     * message letting them know.
     */

     if(isset($_SERVER['username'])) {
         echo "You're already registered as $_SESSION[username]";
     }

     // Checks if the form was submitted
     else if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

         /*
          * If both the username and email fields were filled
          * out, save the username in a session variable and 
          * output a thank you message to the browser. To 
          * eliminate leading and trailing whitespace, we use the 
          * trim() function
          */
          if(!empty(trim($_POST['username']))
          && !empty(trim($_POST['email']))) {

              // Store escaped $_POST values in variables 
              $uname = htmlentities($_POST['username']);
              $email = htmlentities($_POST['email']);

              $_SESSION['username'] = $uname;
              echo "Thanks for registering! <br />",
              "Username: $uname <br />",
              "Email: $email <br />";
          }

          /*
           * If the user did not fill out both fields, display 
           * a message letting them know that both fields are 
           * required for registration
           */

           else {
               echo "Please fill out both fields! <br />";
           }
     }

     // If the form was not submitted, dispalys the HTML form

     else {

?>

<?php } ?>
```

When I output both of the files on the browser, the browser reports that: **Fatal Error:** Can't use function value in write context in 'path of the file' and line of the code.

Please help out by fixing this and feel free to add on anything that you might find useful for me. Thanks in Advance...

Comment: What's the line of code the error refers to?

Comment: the code refers to line 25

Comment: And which is line 25?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues I can see with your code.

```
 if(isset($_SERVER['username'])) {
     echo "You're already registered as $_SESSION[username]";
 }
```

Should be

```
 if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
     echo "You're already registered as ".$_SESSION['username'];
 }
```

Also, you're looking for a `$_POST` variable called `username` when your form field is called `name`.

As for the actual error you're seeing, that's because of the way you're using `empty` and `trim` together - you should check the 2 separately. E.g.

```
$uname = isset($_POST['username']) ? trim($_POST['username']) : '';
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? trim($_POST['email']) : '';
if(!empty($uname)  && !empty($email)) {
```

Comment: This is a great answer indeed, but for some reason, the browser doesn't run the <b>else if</b> statement. It runs <b>else</b> even if I fill in the form...

Comment: Perhaps `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` isn't set to `POST` - what do you get if you `echo` it? Personally, I'd use `elseif (!empty($_POST))` instead.

Comment: It works when I echo it, but doesn't when I include the if statement. Sorry to be such a brag man. Perhaps I need to spend some more time learning this. But unfortunately, this is the only example I have on the book...

Comment: Did you try `!empty($_POST)` instead? When you say it "works" when you echo it, what do you mean? Really to help any further I think I'd have to see your updated code - perhaps you should post a new question.

Comment: Okay. Let me post the updated post. I'm also new to Stack Overflow and I'm thankful for all the help that you are giving me...

Comment: I have just posted the updated code in the new question that I have just asked...

Answer (score 0):

I tink its going to be a good idea to trim your variables after receiving them trom the global variable before checking if they arer empty

```
        $uname = trim($_POST['username']);
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
      if(!empty($uname)  && !empty($email)) {
    //if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['email']))
    //{

          // Store escaped $_POST values in variables 
          $uname = htmlentities($_POST['username']);
          $email = htmlentities($_POST['email']);

          $_SESSION['username'] = $uname;
          echo "Thanks for registering! <br />",
          "Username: $uname <br />",
          "Email: $email <br />";
      }
```